# How do I implement sorting on a YUI DataTable which uses struts data?

Tags: datatable, struts, yui

How do I implement sorting on the below YUI DataTable? The datasource is struts.

```
<yui:datatable containerId="printResults"
               dataSource="userSavedQueries"
               dataSourceType="TYPE_HTMLTABLE"
               dataTableType="ScrollingDataTable"
               width="100%"
               height="11em">
    <s:iterator value='{"Search Name","Domain","Last Modified","Action"}' status="status">
        <yui:datacolumn>
            <jsp:attribute name="key"> 
                <s:property value="top"/>
            </jsp:attribute>
            <jsp:attribute name="label">
                <s:property value="top"/>
            </jsp:attribute>
            <jsp:attribute name="sortable">false</jsp:attribute>
        </yui:datacolumn>
    </s:iterator>
</yui:datatable>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to sort the table by using:
true

This puts sortability on all columns. I am not sure how to implement sorting on only a few specific colums.